# Enabling back button with Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

Following is my `index.jsp`:

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<s:head/>
<sj:head/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
<title>My Air - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainPage">
        <jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <div id="mainContent">
        <jsp:include page="menubar.jsp"></jsp:include>
          <div id="mainContentTop">
            <div id="ContentLeft">
                <jsp:include page="search.jsp"></jsp:include>
            </div>
            <div id="contentRight">
                <jsp:include page="topdeals.jsp"></jsp:include>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my `search.jsp`:

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>\
<s:form action="searchFlight" theme="css_xhtml" cssClass="form1small" name="searchFlightForm">
    <div class="searchHeadersmall">Search Flight</div>
    <div id="searchForm1">
        <s:actionerror/>
        <s:select list="#application.cityList" headerValue="--------Select--------" headerKey="select" name="searchFlightDetails.from" label="Leaving From"></s:select>
        <s:select list="#application.destlist" headerValue="---------Select-------" headerKey="select" name="searchFlightDetails.to" label="Going To"></s:select>
        <sj:datepicker id="date0" label="Date" name="searchFlightDetails.dateoftravel" readonly="true" minDate="0"/>
        <s:select list="#{'1':'1','2':'2','3':'3','4':'4','5':'5'}" headerValue="" headerKey="" name="searchFlightDetails.noofpassengers" label="No of tickets" style="width:50%; float:left"></s:select>
        <div class="inputsmall nobottombordersmall">
            <s:radio label="Type" name="searchFlightDetails.nonstop"
                list="#{'Y':'NonStop','N':'Normal'}"/>
        </div>
        <div id="submitdivid1">
            <sj:submit value="Show Flights" targets="mainContent"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</s:form>
```

When form is submitted the following `searchFlightSuccess.jsp` is loaded in `mainContent` `<div>`:

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<s:if test="#session.username!=null">
    <jsp:include page="menubaruser.jsp"></jsp:include>
</s:if>
<s:if test="#session.username==null">
    <jsp:include page="menubar.jsp"></jsp:include>
</s:if>
<div id="searchHeaderHistory">Search Results</div>
<div class="CSSTableGenerator">
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col span="1" style="width: 5%;">
            <col span="1" style="width: 10%">
            <col span="1" style="width: 15%">
            <col span="1" style="width: 10%">
            <col span="1" style="width: 15%">
            <col span="1" style="width: 15%">
            <col span="1" style="width: 15%">
            <col span="1" style="width: 5%">
            <col span="1" style="width: 10%">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="9">From:<s:property
                        value="searchFlightDetails.from" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    To:<s:property value="searchFlightDetails.to" /></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Flight ID</td>
                <td>Provider</td>
                <td>Departure Source</td>
                <td>Via</td>
                <td>Via Arrival</td>
                <td>Via Departure</td>
                <td>Destination Arrival</td>
                <td>Fare</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <s:iterator value="searchedFlightsList" var="flights">

                <tr>

                    <td align="center"><s:property
                            value="#flights.flightDetails.fid" /></td>
                    <td align="center"><s:property
                            value="#flights.flightDetails.providerDetails.pname" /></td>
                    <td align="center"><s:property value="#flights.sourcedepdate" />,<s:property
                            value="#flights.sourcedeptime" /> hrs</td>
                    <td align="center"><s:property
                            value="#flights.flightDetails.routeDetails.via" /></td>
                    <td align="center"><s:property value="#flights.viaarrdate" />,<s:property
                            value="#flights.viaarrtime" />hrs</td>
                    <td align="center"><s:property value="#flights.viadepdate" />,<s:property
                            value="#flights.viadeptime" />hrs</td>
                    <td align="center"><s:property value="#flights.destarrdate" />,<s:property
                            value="#flights.destarrtime" />hrs</td>
                    <td width="5%" align="center"><s:property
                            value="#flights.flightDetails.fares2d" /></td>
                    <td width="5%" align="center">
                        <s:form
                            action="passengerDetailsLink" method="get" theme="simple"
                            id="passengerDetailsLink_%{#flights.sid}">
                            <s:hidden value="%{#flights.sid}" name="sid" />
                            <s:hidden value="%{#flights.flightDetails.fares2d}" name="fare" />
                            <s:hidden value="%{searchFlightDetails.from}" name="from" />
                            <s:hidden value="%{searchFlightDetails.to}" name="to" />
                            <s:hidden value="%{searchFlightDetails.noofpassengers}"
                                name="passengers" />
                            <s:hidden value="1" name="flag" />
                            <sj:submit value="Book" targets="mainContent"
                                cssClass="orangebuttonsmall" />
                        </s:form></td>

                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The scenario is as follows:

I entered some values in `search.jsp`. I submitted the form, and accordingly some results got loaded into the `mainContent <div>`. Since form was submitted using Struts 2 jQuery plugin submit , the URL remains the same and hence browser back button doesn't work. If I want to go back, how can I do that.

I read about some hash technique but , I am not able to apply it to this.

Answer (score 0):

In the header tag of Struts2 jQuery use `ajaxhistory` attribute. Setting this attribute to `true` enabled browser history for Ajax requests. For details see wiki of [header tag](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/HeadTag#attributes).

Comment: What u suggest is correct. But the problem is that the content of "mainContent" div is replaced by new content. Setting ajaxhistory to true do enable the back button and url also changes in the address bar. But clicking the back button changes the url to previous url but the content of the "mainContent" div is not changed. So only the url changes but not the content.. Any more suggestions, u can help with???

Comment: It should call the ajax requests on back button, but instead of `div` in palace of the content you use should use `sj:div`.